# Ajax browser compatibility

Tags: html, ajax

I am developing a webpage in which I use Ajax in the following way.

```
var xmlhttpres="";
function Ajaxfun(spanUsername,spanPassword)
{

    xmlhttpres=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttpres==null)
    {
            alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
            return;
    }
    var url="CheckExistuser.php";
    url=url+"?Userid="+spanUsername;
    url=url+"&NewPassword="+spanPassword;
    xmlhttpres.onreadystatechange=Vad;
    xmlhttpres.open("POST",url,false);
    xmlhttpres.send(null);
    //alert(url);
}
function Vad()
{
    if (xmlhttpres.readyState==4)
    {
        var Result =xmlhttpres.responseText;

        returnstr = Result.split('~');
        if(returnstr[0]==5001) {
            document.getElementById("Emailexists").style.visibility='visible'; 
            Emailerrflg=1;
        }
        else { 
            document.getElementById("Emailexists").style.visibility='hidden';
            Emailerrflg=0;
        }
            returnstr = Result.split('~');
        if(returnstr[1]==1)
        {
            document.getElementById("Errormatchpwd").innerHTML='Username Already Exists';
            document.getElementById("SRZUsername").select();
            document.getElementById("SRZUsername").focus();
            document.getElementById("Errormatchpwd").style.visibility='visible';
        }
        else
        {   
            //alert("else part");
            Econtd();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine in Internet Explorer. But the function `Vad()` does not get called in Firefox nor in Chrome. After displaying the error message, the page was refreshed. How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Why not use a cross-browser existing library like jQuery?

Comment: jquery ? how can i interact with server by the use of jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a look at: [Make the XMLHttpRequest Object Work Cross-Browser](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/28938/0/page/1)